# Notepad++ Hangs On Close

Tags: windows-8.1, notepad++

I'm using [`Notepad++`](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) on `Windows 8.1`. Until recently it closed just fine when I clicked the X but now when I do so it doesn't close but rather freeze the application. When I repeatedly click the X the window will turn white and `Windows` says that the program is no longer responding then I can make `Windows` kill the process.

In an attempt to fix this issue I uninstalled it using the regular `Windows` program uninstaller but that didn't work either, it got stuck forever on

```
Launching: regsvr32 /u /s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\NppShell_06.dll"
```

[image]

Since an ongoing installer/uninstaller can't be terminated I chose to kill it using `Task Manager`.

Now that the program is no longer registered and half-uninstalled I installed it once again but the freezing issue persisted. I then proceeded to use the thorough [`Revo Uninstaller`](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) and cleaned Notepad++ off the machine. That worked.

I installed Notepad++ once again and the issue was gone. However later on the issue came back. What the heck? How can I fix this once in for all? I'm running the latest version as of now, obviously.

There seems to be an issue with

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\NppShell_06.dll
```

because it's used by some process even when Notepad++ is not running.

Comment: There is not information in your question to diagnose what is going wrong.

Comment: @DavidPostill:
Please tell me what else to include as well then

Comment: `NppShell_06.dll` is the shell integration (open with) for notepad++ so it will be open as part of explorer. You could try removing the shell integration and see if that fixes your problem. See [How to remove shell integration of Notepad++?](http://superuser.com/q/57232)

Comment: @DavidPostill:
I want to keep that though, it always worked fine before. With the shell extension disabled or enabled the issue seems to sometimes happen and sometimes not. Strange.

Comment: I have no further ideas :/

Comment: It happens to me when I have a document open from a network location. I have to make sure I close Notepad++ before I disconnect from the network.

Comment: Have you tried using the portable version?

Comment: Now after a reboot and a clean reinstall it seems to be fixed. PortableApps is not officially supported so it's not the latest version.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue! I just clean-installed Windows and it started happening for the first time ever. Maybe we should send some memory dumps to the author to help him fix this.

Answer (score 7):

The current discussion on the Notepad++ twitter is that its either The DSpellCheck or Plugin Manager plugins.

I deleted DSpellCheck and this issue was fixed,

Comment: How did you deinstall DSpellCheck if it hangs on exit? I click "Remove" and Notepadd says "Must restart" then hangs.

Comment: @DevPlayer with NotePad++ v6.8.1 uninstallation with restart worked without any issues.

Comment: I had to manually delete DSpellCheck.dll from the plugins folder in Windows Explorer.

Comment: This fixed it for me (v6.8.3)

Comment: Fixes the problem in v6.8.9 too. I didn't delete the plugin, just moved it to the ```disabled/``` folder in the NP++ installation directory. You would think by now, 10 sub versions on, that the problem would have been properly fixed.

Answer (score 3):

According to the current update on the Notepad++'s website, there was a bug in the v6.7.9 and they patched it in the v6.7.9.1

**Their Statement:**

> "A critical issue (hanging on exit) and a regression (JavaScript is not recognized in HTML document) have been fixed in 6.7.9.1 release."

This is the
[release page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.7.9.1-released.html) if you would like to check it out yourself.

Comment: Yes, we got them to fix it :)

Comment: I have the same problem with v6.8.3